# Optimal blade/paddle design for low-budget Friction Heater (Joule Machine)

Tags: fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics, heat-transfer

### Generating heat by stirring fluids

I am interested in the direct conversion of mechanical energy into thermal energy as it was done by [James Prescott Joule](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Prescott_Joule). For context: I was inspired by the danish approaches to heating houses with the use of a large [water brake on a wind wheel](https://www.lowtechmagazine.com/2019/02/heat-your-house-with-a-water-brake-windmill.html).

The schematic construction of a 'Joule Machine' in such a wind wheel looks like this:
[image]

*^ Image from lowtechmagazine.com*

The original appratus in the Science Museum, London looks a little bit more complex
[image]

*^ Image from wikipedia.org*

I want to build a (somewhat different) prototype and one main goal is to use readily available materials and as-simple-as-possible production and assembly techniques.

Although I am familiar with CAD construction and basic mechanics, I am a complete noob in thermodynamics and I'm also not very good with such calculations. So I hope you can point me in the right direction with the design of the 'Heat Generator' unit and explain to me the causal relations.

From my pathetic knowledge of physics,

### I assume that

**[A]** all the rotational energy from the input must eventually be converted to heat by the braking system, no matter how it looks. *But since the original Joule Machine is more complex than the above shown schematics, I wonder if it makes some difference 'how hard you brake', or how much of the braking surface points perpendicular to the rotation direction.*

**[B]** the baffles prevent the fluid from just being pushed around in a circular motion (which would cancel out the braking effect).

**[C]** The faster the tip speed of the mixer blades, the more braking torque. So, a flat mixing chamber with a large diameter seems better than a slim shape - but there's a limit where cavitation will occur and damage the machine.

**[D]** The specific heat capacity of water is 4.19 kJ/kg°C, where the specific heat of, say, vegetable oil is 1.76kJ/kg°C (according to [engineeringtoolbox.com](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/specific-heat-fluids-d_151.html)). So the oil would need less braking force to heat up (or heat faster at the same force), but cannot hold as much energy as water (which is ok in my scenario).

### My (naive) questions:

1. Are the above mentioned assumptions at least somewhat correct?
2. I can imagine that flat vertical paddles need to overcome more torque than a rotating 'toilet brush', but what effect would a finer structure (like perforated metal plates) have on the overall performance, especially when wind-driven?
3. Is it necessarily the best option to use flat vertical paddles plus stationary baffles for the fluid brake? For simplicity, I'd rather stack sheet metal pieces with counter nuts on a threaded rod, like in the following picture. Or maybe sheets with bent angles that direct the fluid upwards and/or downwards?
4. Is oil a suitable stirring medium, apart from its obvious properties (non-corrosive, self-lubricating, higher boiling point), when we assume that the heat in the chamber can be extracted fast enough? Is cavitation damage more or less likely to happen in oil than in water?

[image]

Please excuse any foolish thoughts of mine. I am trying hard to get my head around this topic, but I'm seriously lacking proper education... :-)

Thanks a lot for your efforts!